# How to download/install xgboost for python (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

When I do pip install xgboost I get an error as shown below. I believe there is another method using git? But I don't understand how to do that exactly (step by step) - I'm new to this stuff. Help is much appreciated

```
192-168-1-10:Desktop yadav_sa$ pip install xgboost
    Collecting xgboost
      Using cached xgboost-0.6a2.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
        clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
        /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
        clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
        make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
        make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
        /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
        make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
        -----------------------------
        Building multi-thread xgboost failed
        Start to build single-thread xgboost
        rm -f -rf build build_plugin lib bin *~ */*~ */*/*~ */*/*/*~ */*.o */*/*.o */*/*/*.o xgboost
        clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/learner.o src/learner.cc >build/learner.d
        /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
        make: *** [build/learner.o] Error 127
        make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
        clang-omp++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -MM -MT build/logging.o src/logging.cc >build/logging.d
        /bin/sh: clang-omp++: command not found
        make: *** [build/logging.o] Error 127
        Successfully build single-thread xgboost
        If you want multi-threaded version
        See additional instructions in doc/build.md
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/setup.py", line 29, in <module>
            LIB_PATH = libpath['find_lib_path']()
          File "/private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/xgboost/libpath.py", line 45, in find_lib_path
            'List of candidates:\n' + ('\n'.join(dll_path)))
        XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Libarary in the candicate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?
        List of candidates:
        /private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/xgboost/libxgboost.so
        /private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/xgboost/../../lib/libxgboost.so
        /private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/xgboost/./lib/libxgboost.so

        ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/t8/y5n13zb97n1576yvs58vqhm4003cyx/T/pip-build-xcknr88x/xgboost/
```

I need this package for python machine learning. I am on a mac.[image]

Here I followed the official installation guide but I receive an error.

```
192-168-1-10:xgboost yadav_sa$ cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
-bash: cd: xgboost: Not a directory
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -o xgboost  build/cli_main.o build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/common/hist_util.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_fast_hist.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a  -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
c++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -shared -o lib/libxgboost.so build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/common/hist_util.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_fast_hist.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
ar crv lib/libxgboost.a 
ar: no archive members specified
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make: *** [lib/libxgboost.a] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
clangclang: : error: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'unsupported option '-fopenmp'

make: *** [lib/libxgboost.so] Error 1
make: *** [xgboost] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is official installation guide:

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html#installation-guide

Comment: @novice "-bash: cd: xgboost: Not a directory" .  You are probably in "xgboost" directory already. try to run just `cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4` inside xgboost directory

Comment: I tried that, same error, except without `-bash: cd: xgboost: Not a directory`

Comment: what about:
```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```
?

Comment: I see there is a Clang error, did you try using g++ version 4.8 or higher? If that works and you cloned from GitHub, from the `xgboost` dir, run `pip install -e python-package/` to install the python package. It looks like someone had a similar error on OXS: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1501

Answer (score 1):

!pip install xgboost

Just copy and paste the code into your notebook, works like magic

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).